# How do I solve a third order differential equation using ode23 in MATLAB and plot the step response

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I have based my solution off the example provided by [Matlab - solving a third order differential equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754459/matlab-solving-a-third-order-differential-equation).

My problem is that I have to solve the third order differential equation, y'''+3y''+2y'+y=4u, by using the ode23 solver and plot the step response. 
Here is what I have so far.

```
function dy = diffuy( t, y )
%Split uy into variables in equation
%y'''+3y''+2y'+y=4u
%Have to take third order equation and convert to 1st order
%y0 = y
%y1 = y0'
%y2 = y1'
%y3 = y2'

%y0' = y1
%y1' = y2
%y2' = y3
%y3' = y''' = -3*y2-2*y1-y0+4*u
%Assume that y(0)= 0, y'(0)=0, y''(0)=0, no initial conditions
u = @(t) heaviside(t);

dy =  zeros(4,1);
dy(1) = y(2);
dy(2) = y(3);
dy(3) = y(4);
dy(4) = -3*y(3)-2*y(2)-y(1)+4*u(t);
end
```

In my main file, I have the code:

```
[T, Y]=ode23(@diffuy,[0 20],[0 0 0 0]);
figure(1)
plot(T,Y(:,1))


A=[0 1 0;0 0 1; -1 -2 -3]
B=[0;0;4]
C=[1 0 0]
D=[0]

sys4=ss(A,B,C,D)
figure(2)
step(sys4)
```

The problem I am having is that the step response produced from using the state-space representation commands in MATLAB do not match the step response produced by the ode23, so I assumed that I solved the differential equation incorrectly. Any tips or comments would be very helpful.

Step Response from ss commands:
[image]

Step Response from using ode23:

[image]

Comment: Your solution seems reasonable, however I'm unfamiliar with `ss` and friends. Are you positive that you are entering the same system into `ss` to check?

Comment: I am pretty sure that I entered the same system. I guess I'll just have to wait for someone who is familiar with state-space. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: It seems [you're right](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/TF2SS.html#Transfer_Function):)

Comment: Are you intentionally using nonzero initial conditions, contradicting your comments in the code? Your third parameter into `ode23`, `y(t=0)` is nonzero.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! However, I am still not getting the step responses to match. I am not sure if it is because the input, u, I used is the heaviside function, which I have run into problems in the past because of it, or it is something else.

Comment: The Heaviside was my first idea. I checked it with different definitions (i.e. with `H(0)` being 0, 1 and 0.5), and got almost identical solutions. The same goes for `ode45` and stiff solvers. I think your input parameters are off somewhere. Can you post pictures about the two plots you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how the linked question got the correct answer because you're actually solving a fourth-order equation using their methodology.
The right hand-side vector given to the ODE suite should only have *n* entries for an *n*-order problem.

In your case, the change of variables

[image: Change of variables matrix]

results in the third order system

[image: Third order system equation]

with the initial conditions

[image: Initial conditions equation].

Changing `diffuy` to

```
function dy = diffuy( t, y )        
    dy =  zeros(3,1);
    dy(1) = y(2);
    dy(2) = y(3);
    dy(3) = -3*y(3)-2*y(2)-y(1)+4*u(t);
end
```

gives a solution that matches the state-space model.

Comment: o wow, I guess you always have to cross-check answers even though they get up-voted. Thanks a lot, this was helpful.